# Combine characters from two list of unequal length in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 lists of different length, one of numbers and one of characters:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
y = ['A','B','C','D','E','Z','A','B','C','D','E','Z','A','B','C','D','E','F','Z','A','B','C','D','E','Z','A','B','C','D','E','Z','A','B','C','D','E','Z','A','B','C','D','E','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','Z','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','Z','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B']
```

How would I loop through these so that I get the result `1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1Z,2A` etc. (dependent on the numbers/characters in the lists)?

EDIT As I point out in a comment below the character list does not repeat the same set of value, clearer example:

If I have `x = [1,2,3]` and `y=['A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C']`, I would be looking for the answer `1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B, 3C`

Comment: You can use the `for` statement, or try with list comprehension.

Comment: Nested for loop, to be more specific.

Comment: Could you provide a shorter example that more explicitly outlines the algorithm you're looking for?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's definitely `product` he's looking for.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi it's clearly not (or, at least, not *quite*), because if it was there would be a second `1A` for the second `'A'`, not a `2A`. Hence the request for clarification.

Comment: If I have `x = [1,2,3]` and `y=['A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C']`, I would be looking for the answer 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B, 3C

Comment: @jmk I've taken a guess at the algorithm and answered accordingly, but this would be **much easier** if you could explicitly describe what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updated example, I *think* what you want is:

1. Starting with the first digit in the first list;
2. Iterate over the second list and create pairs;
3. Until you reach the first item from the second list again;
4. Then take the next digit from the first list and continue from 2.

On that basis, you could use:

```
def combine(list1, list2):
    list1 = iter(list1)
    for item2 in list2:
        if item2 == list2[0]:
            item1 = next(list1)
        yield ''.join(map(str, (item1, item2)))
```

In use:

```
>>> list(combine([1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']))
['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2B', '3A', '3B', '3C']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = [str(i) + str(j) for i in set(x) for j in set(y)]
```

maybe you should try this

Comment: That does not match the OP's desired output, and using `set`s means the ordering is arbitrary

Answer (score -1):

Since one list is bigger than the other I didn't figure out if you want to limited the new list size by the smallest list size: `x`, and discart all the extra values on `y`. If you want to do this you can try something like:

```
z = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    z.append(str(x[i]) + y[i])
print (z);
```

You need to use the explicity convertion to string `str()` since your first list if of integers.

If you want to extend your first list, so the produced result is `1A 1B 1C 1D 1E...` you can do this:

```
z = [''.join(str(a) + b) for a in x for b in y]
```

Comment: Neither of these suggestions matches the OP's desired output. Additionally, note that `''.join(str(a) + b) == str(a) + b == ''.join((str(a), b))`.